# QDoubleSpinBox: how to reduce the number of digits after the decimal point?

Tags: qt, qtgui

How I can reduce the number of digits after the decimal point?
The default is 6 characters. Too many.
TY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **myspinbox.setDecimals ( int prec )**

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just misunderstood the meaning of 'decimals' :)